# Rails Create new after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, activerecord, callback

In my hospital application ...after I destroy the performance record for the doctor in my show template it deletes the record (docperfdata/83) and redirects to the index page (/docperfdata). But i want it to again go back to the form (/docperfdata/new?hospital_id=15&id=3061) after destroying the record so that the user can enter his data again.

Something like a "Clear all and restart"

How would i achieve the above functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect somewhere else, why not just do that?

```
@docperfdata.destroy

redirect_to(new_docperfdata_path(:hospital_id => @docperfdata.hospital_id, :id => @docperfdata.id))
```

Comment: Thnx very much for yer help ... kindly look at this gist : 
https://gist.github.com/SkyKOG/5394338

its not working @tadman

Comment: resources :performaones, :path => "docperfdata"

i have added this in the routes.rb to make the url more meaningful ....

Comment: This worked :) 
https://gist.github.com/SkyKOG/5394338/#comment-816627
Thnx for the tips ....

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in controller

```
def destroy
  #destroy code here
  redirect_to new_docperfdata_path(:hospital_id=> 15, :id=>3061)
end
```

Comment: its giving an error : undefined method destroy for nil:class... prolly because the object no longer exists to get the ids from and redirect to ...

pls c the above coment